# If I have a separate class for a Piece, and a separate class for a Board, how do I tell the piece to move when they're separate of each other?

Tags: java

The Board class has an 8x8 2D-array of `Piece`s, so I can obviously move a piece with the Board class, by doing `board.move(piece1, 3, left)` for instance, but there's no way I could simply tell the piece to move, like `piece1.move(3, left)`, as there's no way for it to know anything about the board (short of passing it in as a parameter), so it couldn't move itself to a specific index, or know if a piece already occupies this index, or if it's being told to move outside of the bounds of the array.

Comment: You would obviously need some third class, perhaps a "player" or "controller" class.

Comment: @RobertHarvey +1 pieces don't move on their own - players move them. Players know about pieces *and* the board.

Comment: Robert Harvey is right.  The controller will have methods to move pieces on the board.  The advantage of his suggestion is that you can plug in human or computer players without having to rewrite anything.   The controller need not know how the moves are generated.

Comment: Why would you want Piece to implement the move() function anyways?  It wouldn't really make sense.  A piece should just know about itself.

Comment: No, telling the Piece to move is good object-oriented design, but the Piece needs to know about the Board that it's on. When you put the Piece on the Board, you should pass in a reference to the Board. Then, when you tell the Piece to move, it can handle the rest.

Comment: @DavidConrad the idea of object-oriented design is to model real world entities. In the real world, you don't tell chess pieces to move - you pick them up and put them back down somewhere else.

Comment: @MattDavey Telling the piece to move itself isn't good object-oriented design? Tell Alan Kay that.

Comment: @DavidConrad you sound like you have a citation, do you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A piece, by itself, doesn't know anything about where it happens to be placed (and probably doesn't need to know). So there's nothing wrong with needing to call a `Board` method to move a piece.

Answer (score 3):

You have other objects which haven't been modeled yet, such as a `Game` and a `Player`.  Let's take a step back and think about the responsibilities of each of these models:

- **Piece**: A `Piece` is pretty minimal.  It knows what it is, which color it is, that's probably about it.
- **Board**: Also fairly minimal.  It knows what its squares are.
- **Game**: This is probably the most complex component.  It knows the rules of the game.  (After all, if you ever want to change the rules of the game then you shouldn't have to also change the `Board` or the `Piece`, right?)  It knows which `Pieces` make up a complete game set.  It knows which moves each `Piece` can make.  It knows where any given `Piece` is on the `Board` at any given time.
- **Player**: The `Player` interacts with the `Game`.  It will tell the `Game` that it wants to perform a given action on a `Piece`.  The `Game` will allow or deny that action, and modify the state of the `Game` (Check, Mate, Stalemate, other `Player`'s turn, etc.) based on that action.  (Again, the `Pieces` and the `Board` don't care about these states.)

If the `Game` object becomes bloated and unwieldy, it can probably be broken into pieces and exist mostly as a composite object.  You can have a `MoveList` of possible moves for a given set of rules, for example.  The `Game` is composed of it, but doesn't need to internally contain it.

The more I think about it, the more I think that `Board` and `Piece` are set apart as really "dumb" objects in this domain.  They're not even really entities, just value objects.  One piece which has the exact same attributes as another piece is essentially interchangeable with that other piece.  (If you lose a Black Bishop you can replace it with another Black Bishop and not have any adverse effect on the experience.)  The domain might work more fluidly if these two are treated as immutable data structures instead of models.

(It's also worth noting that the same `Board` can be re-used by other `Games` with entirely different sets of `Piece`s.)

As an exercise, I recommend following [Robert Martin's Bowling Game Kata](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.TheBowlingGameKata).  You'll be surprised how much effort you can put into modeling a game domain only to have it turn out to be a *lot* simpler when you consider the actual tests to validate the domain.  We can academically think about these chess models all day long, but coming up with a few tests to validate the game can emerge a simpler design.